# Implementinf Soduko

Tags: python

Im trying to put in valid numbers into the board and meet all the conditions for the game.
The code doesnt run for some reason.

```
board = [
    [0,0,6,9,0,5,0,1,0],
    [9,7,0,0,1,2,3,0,5],
    [0,2,0,0,0,4,8,6,0],
    [5,0,3,8,0,0,0,2,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,8,0,0,0,1,9,0,7],
    [0,5,4,1,0,0,0,7,0],
    [2,0,7,4,5,0,0,9,3],
    [0,6,0,7,0,3,1,0,0]
]

#cheking that the 3x3 squares dont have sum of 45, game continues if False

def check_conditions():
    a = board[0][0:3] + board[1][0:3] + board[2][0:3]
    b = board[3][0:3] + board[4][0:3] + board[5][0:3]
    c = board[6][0:3] + board[7][0:3] + board[8][0:3]
    d = board[0][3:6] + board[1][1:6] + board[2][1:6]
    e = board[3][3:6] + board[4][1:6] + board[5][1:6]
    f = board[6][3:6] + board[7][1:6] + board[8][1:6]
    g = board[0][6:9] + board[1][6:9] + board[2][6:9]
    h = board[3][6:9] + board[4][6:9] + board[5][6:9]
    i = board[6][6:9] + board[7][6:9] + board[8][6:9]


all_squares = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
for i in all_squares:
    if sum(i) != 45:
        return False

#checking for duplicate in row, this function is under check_conditions()


 for i in board:
        if len(i) != len(set(i)):
            return False


#checking that there no zeros in the board

def zero_condition():
    for i in board:
            for j in i:
                if j == 0:
                    return False



#checking for duplicates in column

def get_column(col, board):
    column = []
    for i in range(len(board)):
        column.append(board[i][col])
    return column

all_column = [get_column(0, board), get_column(1, board), get_column(2, board), get_column(3, board), get_column(4, board), get_column(5, board), get_column(6, board), get_column(7, board), get_column(8, board)]


def check_column():
    for i in all_column:
        if len(i) != len(set(i)):
            return False

#putting numbers into chosen rows and column

def choose_cell():

    row = int(input("choose row:"))
    column = int(input("choose column:"))
    choose_num = int(input("choose a num between 1 og 9:"))
    if 0< choose_num <=9:
        board[row][column] = choose_num
    else:
        print("illegal num try again")
        choose_cell()


#this is where the game starts

def begin_soduko():
    answer= input("play soduko?")
    if answer == "yes":
        while zero_condition() == False and check_conditions == False and check_column() == False:
            choose_cell()


print("you have finished soduko!!!")
```

Comment: Are you calling any of your functions?

Comment: @GinoMempin im calling them in the while loop on the bottom, or do i have to call them outside the loop to begin the game? the loop only has one function which is entering numbers into the board,

Answer (score 1):

I copy pasted all your code into a script and attempted to run it. If this is all your code, the first thing you are missing is a call to "begin_sudoku()" before your finishing print statement.

Afterwards, I ran it and was able to be asked whether to play, but entering "yes" still ended the game despite all three conditions being false. I found the last reason your game isn't running is because you are forgetting the parenthesis on "check_conditions()" when checking conditions in the while loop. I added the () to the end of it along with the call to begin_sudoku() and the game ran fine for me.

```
def begin_soduko():
  answer= input("play soduko?")
  if answer == "yes":

    while zero_condition() == False and check_conditions() == False and check_column() == False:
        choose_cell()

begin_soduko()
print("you have finished soduko!!!")
```

Replace your last code block with this and it should finally run.